# BuddyPress - Redirects on Login and Logout

Tags: redirect

Using BP theres a way to:

```
1. On login redirect to member profile.

2. On logout redirect to facebook.com
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

heres how you login to the profile page.

```
/*Add a filter to filter the redirect url for login*/
add_filter("login_redirect","bpdev_redirect_to_profile",100,3);
function bpdev_redirect_to_profile($redirect_to_calculated,$redirect_url_specified,$user)
{
/*if no redirect was specified,let us think ,user wants to be in wp-dashboard*/
if(empty($redirect_to_calculated))
    $redirect_to_calculated=admin_url();

    /*if the user is not site admin,redirect to his/her profile*/
    if(!is_site_admin($user->user_login))
        return bp_core_get_user_domain($user->ID);
    else
        return $redirect_to_calculated; /*if site admin or not logged in,do not do anything much*/

}
```

and heres to logout to facebook

```
add_filter('allowed_redirect_hosts','allow_ms_parent_redirect');
function allow_ms_parent_redirect($allowed)
{
    $allowed[] = 'facebook.com';
    return $allowed;
}

<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( 'http://facebook.com' ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Where/what file is this code added to?

Comment: This can be added to your functions file of your theme.